# Displaying posts of given category

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I'm facing a strange problem:

```
  <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'ff', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
              while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

(...)

              <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This code displays all posts of "ff" type. Works fine.

But I do not want to list all posts of this type, I just want the ones that are in "ff_show" category (so the slug/term is "ff_show).

Codex tells me that I should use 'category_name' but when I do the loop is always empty:

```
  <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'ff', 'category_name' => 'ff_show',  'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
```

I've tried typing everything after 'category_name', nothing works.

The funny thing is when I use category instead of category_name - it ALWAYS shows all the posts. No matter what ID I give.

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm sure about my category name, it is exactly as I said.

When I login to my panel admin and go to categories and hover over one of them it points to:

> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=frontpage_categories&post_type=ff&tag_ID=19

BUT 'cat' => '19' shows nothing.

:/

Comment: What makes you think the `cat` parameter would work on the edit-tags page? Why does it need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure `ff_show` is correct slug? I have suspicions about that underscore...

`category` is not valid query argument at all, it is probably simply discarded.

Had you tried this query with id instead of slug? `cat` argument.

**Edit.**

Wait, you are trying to query custom taxonomy? Category arguments have no relation to it at all.

Try `frontpage_categories => ff_show` (quick guess, don't remember specifics of querying custom stuff. again - not my area).

Yeah, found it at last [Custom Taxonomies > Querying by Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Taxonomies#Querying_by_taxonomy)

Comment: Updated. Nothing :( Anyways - is my code valid and should work? If it is then I'll search somewhere else...

Comment: I am not sure about how `post_type` interacts with stuff (custom posts are not my area really), but I can't spot anything out of order with code so far. Can you simply query for category without rest of arguments?

Comment: new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'ff', 'category_name' => 'ff_show' ) ); - gives no results. I'm really 100% it's named that way because I'm just looking at category tables ;/

Comment: try changing `category_name` to `category`. custom post types should take the taxonomy term name as argument